# Getting items updated after a certain date

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, list-item

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 [List/ListItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem) API to access the documents on my Sharepoint Site.

I am looking for filters that can query items modified after a certain date. By modification I mean any update to the document (editing, sharing, renaming etc and also any new documents added to the Site)

Is this possible using this API? I am able to fetch new items using the `$filter=ID gt <id>` filter, but I am unable to retrieve items updated after a certain date. I am also able to query documents whose content has been updated after a certain date (using the filter on `Modified` field in the item metadata)